# How can I layout gdb to show regs, src code, and disasm, at the same time?

Tags: debugging, memory, gdb, disassembly

gdb shows great information in `layout regs` and `layout split`.  How can I get it to show *both*? I'd like to see regs, src code, disasm (and maybe memory) at the same time - ideally with resizeable windows.

I know this is possible, because tools like `pwndbg` do it.  However, I'm working on a embedded program where pwndbg isn't applicable.  If I could show output similar to it, it would be perfectt.

Comment: You can create custom layouts with [`tui new-layout`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html#index-tui-new_002dlayout).